# Sum a column of data in a 2d array

Tags: php, sum, array-column

How can I get the addition of the total_qty_ordered of all the arrays?

This can be any number of arrays

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [1] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [2] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [3] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [4] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [5] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [6] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [7] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [8] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [9] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 2.0000 [1] => )
    [10] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
    [11] => Array ( [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [1] => )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($item){
  return $item['total_qty_ordered'];
}, $array));
```

But if your array structure is really that (2nd value is really empty), you can also do:

```
$sum = array_sum(call_user_func_array('array_merge',
            array_map('array_values', $array)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.5 you can do:

```
 $sum = array_sum(array_col('total_qty_ordered', $array));
```